# How to write xpath for below code displayed on Image

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

[Snapshots displayed Field as well as Inspect element code. Always faced problem on writing xpath for table element. Xpath copied from Moxilla firbugs is worked sometimes but not always.. can any one tell how to write xpath of above code.... Thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLm68.jpg)

Comment: Kindly click on above lines to see the screen shots ...

Comment: Plzz help how to write xpath of code:
<div class="pbSubsection">
<table class="detailList" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="labelCol">Finance Method</td>
<td class="dataCol col02">Business Lease</td>
<td class="labelCol">Pre-qualified Loan Amount</td>
<td class="dataCol"/>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>

Comment: Please post the HTML as text. Images will eventually no longer be available and this question will be less useful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this xpath
`//table[@class='detailList']/tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'Business Lease')]`